# When a div of images wraps, possible to treat the wrap like a span?

Tags: html, css, image

I have a `div` full of images:

```css
.species {
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-top: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.animals {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: 25px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.animal {
  width: 25px;
  padding: 8px 2px 0 2px;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="species">
  <div class="animals">
    <img class="animal" src="ant.png">
    <img class="animal" src="ant.png">
    <img class="animal" src="ant.png">
    <img class="animal" src="ant.png">
    <img class="animal" src="ant.png">
    <img class="animal" src="ant.png">
    <img class="animal" src="ant.png">
    <!-- imagine about 30 more ants -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Since my content well is limited to `600px`, the div (`.animals`) containing the ants wraps, like so:

[image]

But I want it to wrap like a `<span>`, ending with the last ant, like this (created in photo editor):

[image]

However, if I give the parent `<div>` an inline display or change it to a `span`, the parent doesn't expand to the `height` of the images, so I get this:

[image]

[fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/zv3orszy/)

So my question: Is it possible to get the best of both worlds here between `div`s and `span`s, where the container sizes to the `height` of the images but doesn't expand to the `width` of the page on the last row?

I've tried various CSS commands for wrapping text and whitespace, to no avail.

Comment: Thanks for the many great answers, everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `background`  to  `img` instead, and you don't need to have a second parent div `.animals`

```css
.species {
  width: 600px;
  /* as you mentioned in your question */
  margin-top: 20px;
   font-size: 0
  /* fix inline(-block) gap */
}
.animal {
  width: 25px;
  padding: 8px 2px 0 2px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="species">
  <img class="animal" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5bLb.png" />
  <img class="animal" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5bLb.png" />
  <img class="animal" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5bLb.png" />
  <img class="animal" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5bLb.png" />
  <img class="animal" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5bLb.png" />
  <img class="animal" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5bLb.png" />
  <img class="animal" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5bLb.png" />
  <img class="animal" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5bLb.png" />
  <img class="animal" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5bLb.png" />
  <img class="animal" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5bLb.png" />
  <img class="animal" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5bLb.png" />
  <img class="animal" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5bLb.png" />
  <img class="animal" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5bLb.png" />
  <img class="animal" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5bLb.png" />
  <img class="animal" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5bLb.png" />
  <img class="animal" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5bLb.png" />
  <img class="animal" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5bLb.png" />
  <img class="animal" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5bLb.png" />
  <img class="animal" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5bLb.png" />
  <img class="animal" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5bLb.png" />
  <img class="animal" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5bLb.png" />
  <img class="animal" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5bLb.png" />
  <img class="animal" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5bLb.png" />
  <img class="animal" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5bLb.png" />
  <img class="animal" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5bLb.png" />
  <img class="animal" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5bLb.png" />
  <img class="animal" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5bLb.png" />
  <img class="animal" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5bLb.png" />
  <img class="animal" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5bLb.png" />
  <img class="animal" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5bLb.png" />
  <img class="animal" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5bLb.png" />
  <img class="animal" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5bLb.png" />
  <img class="animal" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5bLb.png" />
  <img class="animal" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5bLb.png" />
  <img class="animal" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5bLb.png" />
  <img class="animal" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5bLb.png" />
  <img class="animal" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5bLb.png" />
  <img class="animal" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5bLb.png" />
  <img class="animal" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5bLb.png" />
  <img class="animal" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5bLb.png" />
  <img class="animal" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5bLb.png" />
  <img class="animal" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5bLb.png" />
  <img class="animal" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5bLb.png" />
  <img class="animal" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5bLb.png" />
  <img class="animal" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5bLb.png" />
  <img class="animal" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5bLb.png" />
  <img class="animal" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5bLb.png" />
  <img class="animal" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5bLb.png" />
  <img class="animal" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5bLb.png" />
  <img class="animal" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5bLb.png" />
  <img class="animal" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5bLb.png" />
  <img class="animal" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5bLb.png" />
  <img class="animal" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5bLb.png" />
  <img class="animal" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5bLb.png" />

  <!-- imagine about 30 more ants -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.species {      
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.animals {
    display: table;
    margin: 0;
    margin-right: 25px;
}

 .animal {
    width: 25px;
    background-color: lightblue;  
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top
}
```

fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/zv3orszy/9/

Answer (score 0):

remove `background-color: lightblue;` from `.species` class and add it to image(`.animal`) instead

```
.species {
/* background-color: lightblue; */
margin-top: 20px;
}


.animal {
    width: 25px;
    padding: 8px 2px 0 2px;
    display: inline;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

If you are keen on using inline then you should add `font-size:0;` in #ex1 and #ex2 i.e. parent element to remove the gaps between 
inline and inline-block elements. You can also adjust the padding of images to get them aligned properly according to your need.may be `padding: 8px 4px 2px 4px;`

```
#ex2 {
display: inline-block;
font-size:0;
}
```

```css
#ex1 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0;
}

#ex2 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size:0;
}

.species {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

 .animals {
  //border-bottom: 2px solid gray;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
    margin-right: 25px;
  margin-top: 5px;
 }
  
  .animal {
  width: 25px;
  padding: 8px 4px 2px 4px;
  display: inline;
        background-color: lightblue;

 }
```

```html
<div id="ex1" class="species">
    <div class="animals">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
 </div>
</div>

<div id="ex2" class="species">
    <div class="animals">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Other way to do this is by replacing `margin-top: 20px;` to `padding-top:20px;` for `.species` in your first example. Also `.animals` div is not needed.

**Please see below:**

```css
#ex1 {
  display: inline;
}
.species {
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding-top: 20px; /*padding-top instead of margin-top*/
}
.animals {
  //border-bottom: 2px solid gray;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: 25px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.animal {
  width: 25px;
  padding: 8px 2px 0 2px;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="ex1" class="species">
  <!--<div class="animals">--> <!-- .animals is not needed-->
    <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
    <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
    <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
    <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
    <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
    <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
    <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
    <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
    <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
    <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
    <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
    <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
    <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
    <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
    <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
    <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
    <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
    <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
    <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
    <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
    <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
    <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
    <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
    <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
    <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
    <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
    <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
    <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
    <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
    <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
    <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
    <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
    <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
    <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
    <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
    <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
    <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
    <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
    <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
    <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
    <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
    <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
    <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
    <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
    <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
    <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
    <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
    <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
    <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
    <img class="animal" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/5/2/d/11954389722123324306Andy_-_ant.svg.thumb.png">
  <!--</div>-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should choose your second demo because of the display of container div  `.species` is `inline-block`.

And Set `background-color: light blue;` to `img` tag instead of `. species`.

```css
.species {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 20px;
    font-size: 0;
}

.animals {
    //border-bottom: 2px solid gray;
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
    margin-right: 25px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.animal {
    width: 25px;
    padding: 8px 2px 0 2px;
    /* display: inline; whatever you like*/
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="species">
    <div class="animals">
        <img class="animal" src="ant.png">
        <img class="animal" src="ant.png">
        <img class="animal" src="ant.png">
        <img class="animal" src="ant.png">
        <img class="animal" src="ant.png">
        <img class="animal" src="ant.png">
        <img class="animal" src="ant.png">
        <img class="animal" src="ant.png">
        <img class="animal" src="ant.png">
        <img class="animal" src="ant.png">
        <img class="animal" src="ant.png">
        <img class="animal" src="ant.png">
        <img class="animal" src="ant.png">
        <img class="animal" src="ant.png">
        <img class="animal" src="ant.png">
        <img class="animal" src="ant.png">
        <img class="animal" src="ant.png">
        <img class="animal" src="ant.png">
        <img class="animal" src="ant.png">
        <img class="animal" src="ant.png">
        <img class="animal" src="ant.png">
        <img class="animal" src="ant.png">
        <img class="animal" src="ant.png">
        <img class="animal" src="ant.png">
        <img class="animal" src="ant.png">
        <img class="animal" src="ant.png">
        <img class="animal" src="ant.png">
        <!-- imagine about 30 more ants -->
    </div>
</div>
```